# In Anaconda couldn't download older version of scikit learn package using "pip install scikit-learn==0.21.3" Collecting scikit-learn==0.21.3 Using c

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, version

### I'm getting this error:Collecting scikit-learn==0.21.3
Using cached scikit-learn-0.21.3.tar.gz (12.2 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.0 in c:\users\saiku\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn==0.21.3) (1.20.3)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.17.0 in c:\users\saiku\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn==0.21.3) (1.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\users\saiku\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn==0.21.3) (1.1.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: scikit-learn
Building wheel for scikit-learn (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\saiku\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\saiku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5qbqlc7i\scikit-learn_5b737429b0054d7baa7c92d177b7ccb3\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\saiku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5qbqlc7i\scikit-learn_5b737429b0054d7baa7c92d177b7ccb3\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\saiku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-z7f6sdco'
cwd: C:\Users\saiku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5qbqlc7i\scikit-learn_5b737429b0054d7baa7c92d177b7ccb3
Complete output (33 lines):
Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\saiku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5qbqlc7i\scikit-learn_5b737429b0054d7baa7c92d177b7ccb3\setup.py", line 290, in 
setup_package()
File "C:\Users\saiku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5qbqlc7i\scikit-learn_5b737429b0054d7baa7c92d177b7ccb3\setup.py", line 286, in setup_package
setup(**metadata)
File "C:\Users\saiku\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
config = configuration()
File "C:\Users\saiku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5qbqlc7i\scikit-learn_5b737429b0054d7baa7c92d177b7ccb3\setup.py", line 174, in configuration
config.add_subpackage('sklearn')
File "C:\Users\saiku\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1019, in add_subpackage
config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
File "C:\Users\saiku\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 985, in get_subpackage
config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
File "C:\Users\saiku\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 927, in *get_configuration_from_setup_py
config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
File "sklearn\setup.py", line 76, in configuration
maybe_cythonize_extensions(top_path, config)
File "C:\Users\saiku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5qbqlc7i\scikit-learn_5b737429b0054d7baa7c92d177b7ccb3\sklearn_build_utils_*init**.py", line 42, in maybe_cythonize_extensions
with_openmp = check_openmp_support()
File "C:\Users\saiku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5qbqlc7i\scikit-learn_5b737429b0054d7baa7c92d177b7ccb3\sklearn_build_utils\openmp_helpers.py", line 83, in check_openmp_support
ccompiler.compile(['test_openmp.c'], output_dir='objects',
File "C:\Users\saiku\anaconda3\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 323, in compile
self.initialize()
File "C:\Users\saiku\anaconda3\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 220, in initialize
vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
File "C:\Users\saiku\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 316, in msvc14_get_vc_env
return _msvc14_get_vc_env(plat_spec)
File "C:\Users\saiku\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 270, in _msvc14_get_vc_env
raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-learn
Running setup.py clean for scikit-learn
Failed to build scikit-learn
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn
Running setup.py install for scikit-learn ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\saiku\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\saiku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5qbqlc7i\scikit-learn_5b737429b0054d7baa7c92d177b7ccb3\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\saiku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5qbqlc7i\scikit-learn_5b737429b0054d7baa7c92d177b7ccb3\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\saiku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hlouoqqy\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\saiku\anaconda3\Include\scikit-learn'
cwd: C:\Users\saiku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5qbqlc7i\scikit-learn_5b737429b0054d7baa7c92d177b7ccb3
Complete output (33 lines):
Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\saiku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5qbqlc7i\scikit-learn_5b737429b0054d7baa7c92d177b7ccb3\setup.py", line 290, in 
setup_package()
File "C:\Users\saiku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5qbqlc7i\scikit-learn_5b737429b0054d7baa7c92d177b7ccb3\setup.py", line 286, in setup_package
setup(**metadata)
File "C:\Users\saiku\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
config = configuration()
File "C:\Users\saiku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5qbqlc7i\scikit-learn_5b737429b0054d7baa7c92d177b7ccb3\setup.py", line 174, in configuration
config.add_subpackage('sklearn')
File "C:\Users\saiku\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1019, in add_subpackage
config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
File "C:\Users\saiku\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 985, in get_subpackage
config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
File "C:\Users\saiku\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 927, in *get_configuration_from_setup_py
config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
File "sklearn\setup.py", line 76, in configuration
maybe_cythonize_extensions(top_path, config)
File "C:\Users\saiku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5qbqlc7i\scikit-learn_5b737429b0054d7baa7c92d177b7ccb3\sklearn_build_utils_*init**.py", line 42, in maybe_cythonize_extensions
with_openmp = check_openmp_support()
File "C:\Users\saiku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5qbqlc7i\scikit-learn_5b737429b0054d7baa7c92d177b7ccb3\sklearn_build_utils\openmp_helpers.py", line 83, in check_openmp_support
ccompiler.compile(['test_openmp.c'], output_dir='objects',
File "C:\Users\saiku\anaconda3\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 323, in compile
self.initialize()
File "C:\Users\saiku\anaconda3\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 220, in initialize
vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
File "C:\Users\saiku\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 316, in msvc14_get_vc_env
return _msvc14_get_vc_env(plat_spec)
File "C:\Users\saiku\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 270, in _msvc14_get_vc_env
raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\saiku\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\saiku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5qbqlc7i\scikit-learn_5b737429b0054d7baa7c92d177b7ccb3\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\saiku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5qbqlc7i\scikit-learn_5b737429b0054d7baa7c92d177b7ccb3\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\saiku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hlouoqqy\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\saiku\anaconda3\Include\scikit-learn' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve, what you've done to try to achieve it, and what's going wrong. A full set of error logs can be helpful if properly formatted, but isn't a question by itself.

Answer (score 0):

With the Anaconda Distribution installed you should use the conda package manager, not pip:

```
conda install -c intel scikit-learn=0.21.3
```

It's also a good idea to start with a new virtual environment to not get constraint by unnecessary dependencies, e.g.

```
conda create -n myenv -c intel scikit-learn=0.21.3
```

Comment: I have tried both of these :
conda install -c intel scikit-learn=0.21.3
conda create -n myenv -c intel scikit-learn=0.21.3
But I couldn't solve the issue